# Как достать массив хешей из базы как hash, а не string?

Tags: mysql, ruby, хеширование

В базе у меня есть такая строка

```
 [
{"color"=>"Beige", "title"=>"Icon Shirt", "title_slug"=>"icon_shirt", "brand"=>"Dockers", "brand_slug"=>"dockers", "details"=>"The cotton Alpha Icon button-up shirt by Dockers is a casual and versatile piece that goes with just about anything, so you have one less thing to worry about.", "webid"=>10462837, "pictures"=>["https://...", "https://.."], "main_price"=>59.5, "colors_pic"=>"https://...", "sale_price"=>29.75, "precent_off"=>50, "sizes"=>"S/XL/XXL", "external_id"=>1022},
 {"color"=>"White", "title"=>"Icon Shirt", "title_slug"=>"mens_slim-fit_alpha_icon_shirt", "brand"=>"Dockers", "brand_slug"=>"dockers", "details"=>"The cotton Alpha Icon button-up shirt by Dockers is a casual and versatile piece that goes with just about anything, so you have one less thing to worry about.", "webid"=>10462837, "pictures"=>[""], "main_price"=>59.5, "colors_pic"=>"", "sale_price"=>29.75, "precent_off"=>50, "sizes"=>"S/M/L/XL/XXL", "external_id"=>1143}
]
```

Т.е это 2 товара ( точнее 2 офера товара) в виде массива 2х хешей, я пытаюсь получить обратно это значение из базы, чтобы работать с этими данными :

```
@items__temp = @product.query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = 6161")


@items__temp.each do |item|

  temp__id = item["id"]
  # @items = item["full__desc"].unpack('A6Z6')
  # eval '[ {}, {} ]'
  @string__hash = item["full__desc"] # Это столбец с данными

  @string__hash.slice(1)
  @string__hash.slice(2509)

  # puts @string__hash.extension[1..-1]

  # revert = @string__hash.reverse

  # Пробую пересобрать массив
  @string__hash = @string__hash[1..@string__hash.length]
  @string__hash = @string__hash.reverse[1..@string__hash.length].reverse

  puts @string__hash.split("},")


  @string__hash

  i += 1
end
```

Любые действия с @string__hash как с хешом не проходят, т.к из базы приходит "string" , я пробовал преобразовать через unpack, пробовал пересобрать массив заново через регулярки ( т.е выдернуть данные и создать новые хеши), но не выходит. Я понимаю что лучшим решением было бы хранить json в базе, но удобнее было бы работать сразу с хешами. Что можно попробовать?

Answer (score 2):

MySQL не знает, что такое Ruby Hash и вы ее никак не сможете этому научить. Разве что влезете в код и сделаете свой тип данных.

Ваши попытки сохранить сохранить хэш и запросить хэш обречены на провал по вышеописанной причине. Именно поэтому вы достаете строку, а не хэш — драйвер базы пытается привести тип данных к одному из известных типов и фоллбэком, последним возможным вариантом, конвертирует в строку.

То, что вы хотите сделать называется сериализацией данных. Эта операция обычно используется для передачи данных между двумя точками или хранения в месте,  которое не умеет оперировать нужным типом данных. Как, например, MySQL и Ruby Hash.

Вы напрасно считаете, что таким образом получите более эффективное хранение или удобство в разработке. Если база данных не знает конкретный тип, которым вы пытаетесь оперировать, то в ход идут инструменты из категории «ну хоть как-нибудь», что оставляет за порогом любые варианты оптимизации и вы неизбежно получите дополнительные накладные расходы.

У вас три варианта:

1. Написать свой сериалайзер/десериалайзер, который будет упаковывать хэш в строку и потом распаковывать из нее. Это сложный и затратный вариант. Вам придется вместо работы с товарами и каталогом потратить огромное количество времени на совершенно постороннюю задачу, которая не приблизит вас к успеху, а результат будет так себе.
2. Воспользоваться JSON'ом. Это общепринятый вариант хранения данных с различающейся структурой, быстрее и эффективнее вы ничего не придумаете, люди годами полировали этот вариант. Разве что возьмете MongoDB, но у нее свои тараканы.
3. Разложить данные. Судя по всему ваши данные можно нормально распилить на таблицы и работать как с обычной реляционной базой. В этом варианте вы автоматически обойдете все возможные проблемы нестандартных путей, получите полезные знания и нормальный продукт, который можно будет сопровождать без лишних нервов. Плюс вы всегда найдете ответы на мелкие затруднения, потому что до вас этим путем прошли сотни тысяч разработчиков и у них получилось.